# Probability N points in range

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I have looked for an answer to this problem but I didn't find any.
Apologies if my language is not at the level of this exchange.

In my project, I deal with cells (imagine points of different colors) with coordinates x and y. These cells have different types and they are distributed on a surface.
I am measuring three quantities.

Let's assume we have a square surface of side $L$.  We have $N$ points of type $A$ randomly distributes on this surface, and also $K$ points of type $B$ also randomly distributed on this surface.  We can assume these points to be circular, with radius $r_c$ << L and $r_c$ < D (definition of D follows).

I define the function $S(A, D)$ that gives the number of points "B" at a distance lower than "D" from a point A (so, it's really like looking at how many points fall in the circle centered in point of type A with radius "D").

The first measure is:
$$ M_{sum} =  \sum_{i=1}^N S(A_i, D) $$

The second measure is very similar, it's the average:
$$ M_{avr} =  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N S(A_i, D) $$

For the third measure, I need another function, called $V$.
$$
  V(A, D) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $S(A,D)>0$} \\
0, & \text{if $S(A,D)=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

The measure is:
$$ M_{neig}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N V(A_i,D)$$

The problem is the following.  I need to see if there are any significant differences in my data from a random distribution.
So, is there a way to estimate the expected values for these quantities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average number of B cells within D of an A cell will be
$$M_{avg}\approx \frac{K\pi D^2}{L^2}$$
The proportion of A cells within reach of at least one B cell will be
$$M_{neig}\approx1-\left(1-\frac{\pi D^2}{L^2}\right)^K$$

There are about $\frac{\pi D^2}{\pi r_c^2}$ cells in the circle.  I think $M_{avg}$ stays about the same, but $$M_{neig}\approx1-\frac{(L^2-\pi D^2)/(\pi r_c^2)\choose K}{(L^2)/(\pi r_c^2)\choose K}$$

Comment: This assuming that the cell is an infinite small point?

Comment: Yes, assuming that $D/L$ is so small that a tiny proportion of the $N$ overlap the edge.  I would have to think about the integral that deals with $D/L$ that aren't so small.

Comment: But what about $r_c$?  $r_c < D$ but if $r_c$ is a significant fraction of D, and the cells cannot overlap (maybe I didn't make this point clear in my question, apologies) this should put a limit to the number of neighbors that a cell "A" could have.  Am I wrong?

Comment: There are about $\pi D^2/(\pi r_c^2)$ cells inside the circle and $L^2/(\pi r_c^2)$ cells in total.  I think $M_{avg}$ stays about the same but $M_{neig}\approx  1-{(L^2-\pi D^2)/(\pi r_c^2)\choose K}/{L^2/(\pi r_c^2)\choose K}$.  You can use Stirling's approximation on that.

Comment: May I ask you if you can, please, update the answer?  I don't understand the notation for $M_{neig}$ in the comment.  It looks like a binomial coefficient that has on the top $L^2 -piD^2/(pir_c^2)$.

Comment: Why bother with the algebra here? You could just do a billion Monte Carlo simulations with the configuration you want and check the results.